# QDataStream read to QVector

Tags: c++, qt, qvector, qdatastream

I have a `QByteArray` containing 8 bits representing two floating-point numbers, what is the correct and simplest way to read `QDataStream` to `QVector<float>`?

Code:

```
QByteArray ByteFloatArray;
QVector<float> qVecfloat;
ByteFloatArray.append(0x41);
ByteFloatArray.append(0x31);
ByteFloatArray.append(0x99);
ByteFloatArray.append(0x9A);  // 4 bits float == 11.1

ByteFloatArray.append(0x41);
ByteFloatArray.append(0x31);
ByteFloatArray.append(0x99);
ByteFloatArray.append(0x9A);  // 4 bits float == 11.1

QDataStream myStream(ByteFloatArray);
myStream.setFloatingPointPrecision(QDataStream::SinglePrecision);
myStream >> qVecfloat;
```

Code above gives:

> STD:: bad_alloc at memory location"

I have read related problems, but I can't understand them properly to implement it in my case.

Below is my current solution, but I think it is over complicated and there is a simpler way to do that:

```
QVector<float> qVecfloat;
float myFloat;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {       
    QDataStream myStream(ByteFloatArray);
    myStream.setFloatingPointPrecision(QDataStream::SinglePrecision);
    myStream >> myFloat;
    qVecfloat.append(myFloat);
    ByteFloatArray.remove(0, 4);
    qDebug() << "size " << qVecfloat.size() << " : " << qVecfloat;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [QDataStream::atEnd()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#atEnd) in a loop and read the `float` data like this :

```
QDataStream myStream( ByteFloatArray );
myStream.setFloatingPointPrecision( QDataStream::SinglePrecision );

float f = 0.0f;
while ( !myStream.atEnd() )
{
    myStream >> f;
    qVecfloat.append( f );
}

qDebug() << qVecfloat;
```

Output:

```
QVector(11.1, 11.1)
```